# Поиск библиотеки для распаковки данных

Tags: c++, поиск-библиотек, zlib

Есть задача распаковать данные, запакованные с помощью `zlib` и это делается всего одной функцией из этой библиотеки. Но если у меня из всей библиотеки используется только одна функция, то подтягивать ее всю мне кажется не очень хорошей идеей. Должна же быть какая-нибудь хедер-онли или типа того, либа, содержащая функцию только для распоковки?

Comment: как вариант, прилинкуй статику — всё лишнее линкер должен выкинуть... правда если линкуешь её в другую либо, возможно, будут некоторые трудности... в любом случае ИМХО libz — это не что-то монструозно-огромное, чего нужно избегать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer неприемлимое решение, так как я хочу отказаться от использования zlib, а не "облегчить" сборку

Comment: тогда в чём смысл отказа от zlib?.. как вариант из гугла — [miniz](https://code.google.com/archive/p/miniz/).

Comment: @Fat-Zer вы видимо вопрос не прочитали: мне не нужно заменять одну библиотеку на другую - мне просто нужна одна(!) функция из библиотеки. Так как она одна, я не хочу тянуть за ней всю библиотеку, а взять какую-нибудь хэдэр-онли, которая реализует только эту функцию. Я это в вопросе написал

Comment: гм... просто не вижу ни каких причин делать относительно тяжёлый алгоритм, работающий только с сырыми данными хедер-онли... ну да ладно, у всех свои причуды... удачи в поисках...

Comment: @Fat-Zer я конечно понимаю, что читать тяжело, а понимать прочитанное еще тяжелее, но слова "или типа того" вроде как означают либо так, либо что-то похожее

Comment: я уже два похожих, на мой взгляд, варианта предложил, но тебе не понравилось ;)... могу ещё предложить что-то банально-издевательское вроде «выдрать нужные функции из оригинальной библиотеки и запихнуть их в хедр, приписав `inline`»